# Grammaticalization of third person singular -s

Tags: present-tense

Is there any evidence that the third person singular -s can be traced back to a lexical item before it became an inflection ? I am trying to see if the theory of grammaticalization applies to its diachronic process. Any information would be most helpful. Thanks so much.

Comment: PIE **-ti* --> PGmc **-di* / **-ði* --> AS *-t / -ð* --> ME *-s* (northern) / *-th* (southern) --> ModE *-s* is how I've seen it. Late, the northern dialect of Middle English [used *-s* instead of *-th*, under the influence of Norse *-sk*](http://books.google.com/books?id=UcM7sN3idSgC&lpg=PA93&ots=ufT58QDiYF&dq=english%20-s%20third%20person%20singular%20ending%20history&pg=PA96#v=onepage&q=english%20-s%20third%20person%20singular%20ending%20history&f=false). Eventually this displaced the *-th* altogether. But it seems to be inflectional all the way back to PIE.

Comment: belongs on [linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Yes, linguisticsSE would be more appropriate. Interesting question, though.

Comment: *On topic here*. We specifically invite linguists and etymologists to ask and answer questions, and we specifically invite questions about English grammar and etymology. A question about the history of third person singular -s is a question of English etymology and grammar on the face of it. *Off topic at linguistics.se*. "If you have questions about a single language (if the question only concerns that language), this might not be your place; in such a case, consider visiting the Language related StackExchange sites."

Answer (score 3):

Almost certainly not. The usual 3rd person singular inflection in Old English was *-th* or *-eth* and it looks as if its replacement by *-s* came about by a process of sound change.

Comment: Thanks Berrie, all the evidence thus far has pointed me in that same direction.

Comment: @Barrie England, I've found this comment 3 years late, being new to Stack Exchange, but isn't it odd that English, which has always had the 2 'th' sounds, 'chose' to switch them to 's' in just one situation?

Answer (score 2):

I will promote my comment to an answer here too.

PIE *-ti* -> PGmc *-di/-ði* -> AS *-t/-ð/-þ* -> ME *-th* (Southern)/ *-s* (Northern) -> ModE *-s*

The Northern *-s* came from the influence of Norse mediopassive -*sk*; eventually the Northern usage became standard in Modern English. According to this, the form has been inflectional at least back to late PIE.

Comment: Glad to help :)